# Avoiding assumption with sledgehammer

Tags: isabelle

Please how I can avoid some assumptions or some lemmas when I use sledeghammer? is there such away to do that? becuase I'm sure that there is another methods or lemmas to solve my sublemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facts marked with the attribute `[no_atp]` will not be passed to Sledgehammer. So if you declare your lemmas or assumptions with `[no_atp]`, then sledgehammer should not be able to use them.